# L0 norm, L1 norm and L2 norm

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

For vector $\boldsymbol{x},\boldsymbol{y} \in \mathcal{R}^{n}$, if 
\begin{equation}
\| \boldsymbol{x} \|_0 = \| \boldsymbol{y} \|_0
\end{equation}
What relationship will $\| \boldsymbol{x} \|_1$ and  $ \| \boldsymbol{y} \|_1$(or $\| \boldsymbol{x} \|_2$ and  $ \| \boldsymbol{y} \|_2$) have?

Comment: None. You can multiply $y$ by any nonzero scalar and it doesn't change the $L^0$ norm.

Comment: Except the relations following from the [norm equivalence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_%28mathematics%29#Properties), there's nothing more what can be said in general.

Answer (score 7):

The $L_0$ norm is the number of non-zero elements in a vector. Then it is not strictly a measure of a distance, then you couln't say the equality directly implies a relation between $ \Vert x \Vert _1, \Vert y \Vert _1 $ ...
It is more likely to be interpreted as a measure of sparsity, to find the sparsest solution to a set of equations.